# How can I fix "The instance of entity type XXX cannot be tracked" when only performing a db.SaveChangges()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ef-core-2.1

I have the following code on the `EndEdit` function of an object that implements `IEditable`:

```
    public void EndEdit()
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            if (Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                db.Add(this);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var worklog = db.Find<Worklog>(Id);
                worklog.Comment = Comment;
                worklog.JiraIssue = JiraIssue;
                worklog.Ticks = Ticks;
                worklog.StartDate = StartDate;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

After performing edits on the object, `db.Entry` shows one entity on the context with a state of modified which is what I would expect. However when I call `db.SaveChanges` after executing the else block I get the following error message:

> The instance of entity type 'Worklog' cannot be tracked
>   because another instance with the key value '{Id:
>   b8476f6e-aab6-408f-ab75-f4944b9a0262}' is already being tracked. When
>   attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with
>   a given key value is attached.

Could this somehow be related to the fact that I'm trying to save the `IEditable` object directly into the database?

Super confused any help would be welcome!

Stack Trace:

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Boolean force)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func`3 handleNode)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func`3 handleNode)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState entityState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.NavigationReferenceChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.NavigationReferenceChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectNavigationChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager stateManager)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.TryDetectChanges()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at TimeTracker.ViewModels.WorklogViewModel.EndEdit() in C:\TimeTracker\ViewModels\WorklogViewModel.cs:line 120
```

Entity Class:

```
public class Worklog: IGuidEntity
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public long Ticks { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public virtual JiraIssue JiraIssue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TimeTrackerWorklog> OriginalWorklogs { get; set; }

    public virtual TimeTrackerWorklog UserModifiedWorklog { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class WorklogViewModel : Worklog, IEditableObject
{
    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        return;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        using (var db = new TimeTrackerContext())
        {
            if (Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                db.Add(this);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var worklog = db.Find<TimeTrackerWorklog>(Id);
                worklog.Comment = Comment;
                worklog.JiraIssue = JiraIssue;
                worklog.Ticks = Ticks;
                worklog.StartDate = StartDate;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which of the two `if` blocks is failing? Also what is `TimeTrackerWorklog` (assuming the shown entity type is `Worklog`)?

Comment: Hi, @IvanStoev. The error occurs when the else code path executes. And TimeTrackerWorklog is Worklog. Just got the naming wrong when writing it up. Sorry about that. Have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Ok, the code shown cannot generate such exception, so there must be something not shown here. Some custom code (override) in `SaveChanges`? Or change tracking event handler? Navigation property (what is `JiraIssue`)? Also posting the exception stack trace might help identifying the source of the issue.

Comment: Hey, @IvanStoev. You were right it was related to the JiraIssue navigation property. If I retrieved that from the context before calling save changes it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a little late post but ... I would recommend to separate the code from the Model to Database access, in your case the object to updated is an instance of the class itself. What I would do is to create a class called WorkLogDAL and copy and change the method EndEdit(WorkLog workLog) then the else method would be something like:

```
else
{
   db.TimeTrackerWorklog.Attach(workLog);
   db.Entry(workLog).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```